# Is there any way to get around including an unreachable return statement in go?

Tags: return, switch-statement, go

I have the following function:

```
func fitrange(a, x, b int) int {
    if a > b {
        a, b = b, a
    }
    switch true {
    case x < a:
        return a
    case x > b:
        return b
    default:
        return x
    }
}
```

The go compiler complains that the "function ends without a return statement" even though every possible path through the `switch` statement returns a value. Is there any way to get around this other than adding a dummy `return` statement at the end of the function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of adding a return at the end, you can also pacify the compiler by adding a panic.  It's not a bad idea because if your code contains a bug and that "unreachable" line is ever reached, your program will halt promptly rather than plow ahead with a potentially wrong answer.

Comment: While this is true, I do not believe it deserves to be the right answer. The only time a `panic("unreachable")` at the end of a function makes sense is when you have an infinite for loop that never breaks.

Comment: @StephenWeinberg: I disagree. `panic("Unreachable")` is far far better than a return statement that you don't think can ever be hit, because a) it's signalling the programmer's expectation that this code is unreachable, and b) a return statement that's expected to never be hit is probably not going to return something sensible, so it's better to panic than to potentially corrupt data.

Comment: That is true, but in the example code you could move the default to the end of the function. It would have the same effect without using a `panic`. See Ryan's answer. I have no problem with the use of `panic`, but only after you are reasonably sure there is no way to modify the code to have the last statement be a return.

Comment: It's worth noting this is a bug in the compiler anyway, see http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=65 and in light of that, I'd opt for `panic("unreachable")` for clarity, or even `panic("bug #65")` pending its fix

Answer (score 10):

Remove the `default` case all together and `return x` after the switch.

Like:

```
func fitrange(a, x, b int) int {
    if a > b {
        a, b = b, a
    }
    switch true {
    case x < a:
        return a
    case x > b:
        return b
    }
    return x
}
```